# ForgotYourPassword using Vb.net form and code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, password-recovery

the problem :-
table consist of : `CompanyID`, `CompanyName`, `CompanyPwd`, `CompanyLogo`, `Email`

i need `ForgotYourPassword Code` :

Send an email to Company Email Using Vb.net.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a security question and answer column. There are samples circulation on the net and all you have to do is to `SEARCH`. Look at this example: (*It will send an email to a user*)

```
Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
Dim mail As New MailMessage()
SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "password")
SmtpServer.Port = 587
SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
mail = New MailMessage()
mail.From = New MailAddress("YOURusername@gmail.com")
mail.To.Add("TOADDRESS")
mail.Subject = "Test Mail"
mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL"
SmtpServer.Send(mail)
MsgBox("mail send")
```

But before you execute above, you should fetch the password from your table:

```
SELECT CompanyPwd FROM tableName WHERE Email = '';
```

Comment: you mean this sentence  dim thepassword as string thePassword = (New TextField("",Settings.Connection1DataAccessObject.ExecuteScalar("SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Email = '" & theEmailAddress & "'"))).GetFormattedValue()

Comment: i have an error in TextField and Select Sentence Should be "Select CompanyPwd From Company Where Email = & TheEmailAddress & ""))).GetFormattedValue()